# Creating a nested array dynamically with for loop

Tags: php, laravel

I have a loop that looks like this

```
$folder = [];

$explode = explode("/", $product->folder);

for($i = 0; $i < count($explode); $++)
{
    $folder[$i] = 'test'
}

dd($folder);
```

what I'm trying to do here is to create a nested array depending on how many folders there are based on what I get from `$explode`.

So ideally what I want is this

```
[
    "folder1" => [
        "folder2" => "test"
    ]
]
```

and it would carry on being nested, so if my `$product->folder` looks like this `cat1/cat2/cat3` then the array would looks like this

```
[
    "cat1" => [
        "cat2" => [
            "cat3" => "product"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: so the product value is the last element of array?

Comment: Yep it's the last one.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can build nested array using JSON string and convert into array using `json_decode`

```
$path = 'cat1/cat2/cat3/cat4/product';

$folders = explode('/',trim($path,'/'));
$last = array_pop($folders);

$folders = str_replace(': []',': "'.$last.'"',
  array_reduce(array_reverse($folders),function($carry,$item) {
    if($carry) {
      return '{"'.$item.'": '.$carry.'}';
    }
    return '{"'.$item.'": []}';
  })
);

$folders = json_decode($folders,true);

// Test
print_r($folders);
```

and it will be result as :

```
Array
(
    [cat1] => Array
        (
            [cat2] => Array
                (
                    [cat3] => Array
                        (
                            [cat4] => product
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and formatted result

```
[
    "cat1" => [
        "cat2" => [
            "cat3" => [
                "cat4" => "product"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for your problem

```
$path = 'cat1/cat2/cat3/product';
$folder = [];
$explode = explode("/", $path);
for($i = 0; $i < count($explode)-1; $i++)
{
    if($i+1 >= count($explode)-1)
        $folder[$explode[$i]] = $explode[$i+1];
    else
        $folder[$explode[$i]] = '';
}
```

print_r($folder) result will be this

```
Array ( [cat1] => [cat2] => [cat3] => product )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

```
// Add product title first.
$folder = end($explode);

// Iterate over categories to create a nested array.
for ($counter = count($explode) - 2; $counter >= 0; $counter--) {
    $folder = [$explode[$counter] => $folder];
}
```